# Get rows where the specific value is present and if its not there then display the one with other value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a condition when user changes his mail id the status column value changes to 100. If the mail id is not changed then the value in status column will be 10. The id will be the same always for a user.

```
ID      MAIL            Status
10248   xyz@xyz.com      10
10248   xyz1@xyz.com     100
10241   abc@abc.com      10
10249   pqr@pqr.com      10
10249   pqr1@pqr.com     100
10250   kbc@kbc.com      10
10251   axc@axc.com      10
```

So, from this if the mail id has been changed then get the row with the new mail id. Like if status 100 is present for a id then display the row of that id and don't display status 10 row for that id. If there is no status 100 for a id then display row with status 10.

I tried this but it returns both the status for a id.

```
SELECT id, mail, IF(status=100, status=100,status=10)
FROM table1;
```

so, for ID 10248 and 10249, I expect only the row with status 100.

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, here's what you're trying to do:

- if there is a row for a user with `status code = 100`, return that row
- otherwise, return the row with `status code = 10`

If your version (8.0+) supports window functions, you can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT id, mail
FROM (
  SELECT id, mail, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
      PARTITION BY id ORDER BY 
        CASE status 
          WHEN 100 THEN 0 -- Give status = 100 first priority
          WHEN 10 THEN 1 -- Give status = 10 second priority
          ELSE 2 -- Give anything else last priority
        END
    ) AS RowNum
  FROM table1
) src
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Comment: There is no need for case statement in order by clause. You an simply order that in descending order and just pick RowNum = 1.

Comment: In this simplified example of two fixed status codes, you are correct.  The way I wrote it makes sure it will still work if there are any new status codes added (i.e. `status code = 0 or 1000`)

Answer (score 0):

I Guess This Code will Help you get your Required Result

```
SELECT id,mail,Status
FROM    (
            SELECT id,mail,Status, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by id order by Status desc)RN FROM #temp
        )m
WHERE    m.RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? :)

```
 SELECT  t1.ID , t1.MAIL, (
        SELECT t2.Status
         FROM table1 as t2
         WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID  -- connect
         DESC t2.Status DESC -- show latest
        LIMIT 1  -- get only TOP
    ) as currentstat
 FROM table1 as t1
 GROUP BY t1.ID
```

Will show 100 if 100 exists.
Will show 10 if 100 did not exist. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use union as below, First we are collecting if `status 100 is present for a id` then we collect other status value, means whose email id is not changed yet and status is still 10

```
select * from test where Status = 100
union
select t.* 
from test t
left join test t1 on t1.id = t.id
    and t1.Status = 100
where t1.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

if you would not create procedure and don't have ORM:

```
select b.id,b.mail,b.status from table1 b
left join (
           select  a.id,max(a.status) as status  from table1 a
           group by a.id) c on c.id = b.id  
where c.status=b.status
```

mysql version 5.8 **not needed** for this query

Comment: Nice. This looks pretty simple to implement but won't run for extra test cases

Comment: what's your test casess? add it to new question if you like.